Is the explanation of the video 'Bernoulli's Principle on Atomic Scale' correct?
I saw a video explaining at a microscopic level that places with high speed have lower static pressure. This video suggests that at the microscopic level, the larger the velocity component in the flow direction, the smaller the velocity component perpendicular to the flow direction. The velocity component perpendicular to the flow direction determines the magnitude of static pressure.
I think the explanation in this video is incorrect.

As shown in the figure, this is a pipeline that narrows from wide to narrow, and the ideal fluid flows from left to right with a constant flow rate. Obviously, from the AA section to the DD section of this pipeline, the velocity of the fluid is constantly increasing, which means that the fluid has a positive acceleration.
Therefore, the static pressure of the BB section must be lower than that of the AA section, because the mass of the fluid from the BB section to the DD section is smaller than that from the AA section to the DD section. Because $F=ma$, assuming a remains constant, the smaller $m$, the smaller $F$.
Similarly, the static pressure of CC section is smaller than that of BB section, and the static pressure of DD section is smaller than that of CC section.
Is my explanation correct or is the explanation in the video correct?

I even think it seems very simple, such as a rigid cone. If you push the cone along the axis at the bottom of the cone to obtain acceleration, the stress on different sections of the cone will also be different, and the stress will decrease from the bottom to the top of the cone.
Reference resources:
Bernoulli's Principle on Atomic Scale

Your idea is correct, but it is not at all an explanation. The pressure difference is indeed the source of the forces needed for acceleration. But then you would have to explain why the net pressure change is solely in the forward direction, when the neck clearly is enforcing some radial velocity pattern. I am sceptical of the video too, but yours is not an explanation at all.

@naturallyInconsistent  I even think it seems very simple, such as a rigid cone. If you push the cone along the axis at the bottom of the cone to obtain acceleration, the stress on different sections of the cone will also be different, and the stress will decrease from the bottom to the top of the cone.

Can you outline the arguments in the video, otherwise this is likely to be closed as unclear as it currently requires us going off-site and watching a 6 minute video to determine what that argument is.

@KyleKanos I highlighted the viewpoint of the video in bold font and removed the link to the video. Is that okay?

Bernoulli's Principle applies to continuum fluid dynamics, meaning that fluids are assumed to be continuous at the smallest scales. As a result, atomic motions are irrelevant.

@enbin: a link to the video is fine so long as you're highlighting their remarks in the post body (which makes the video supplemental to your question).

@KyleKanos Thank you very much for your comment.
